# iOS 15 Hiding navigation bar on landscape

Tags: ios, reactjs, material-ui, mobile-safari

Before iOS 15, I was able to show the site fullscreen while scrolling down. This gesture hid the address and tabs bar (navigation bar) as showed on the gif bellow:

[image: iOS12.4 hiding navigation bar]

But something changed on iOS Safari and now this gesture doesn't hide it anymore:

[image: iOS15.2 unable to hide navigation bar through scrolling]

I created a simple [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ios-landscape-issue-rqmpy?file=/demo.tsx) to demo this, using Material-UI (MUI) v5 with the [CSS Baseline component](https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/)

The code:

```
export default function Demo() {
  const [landscapeAvailableHeight, setLandscapeAvailableHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLandscapeAvailableHeight(
      Math.min(window.screen.availHeight, window.screen.availWidth)
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: "tomato"
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: "green",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: landscapeAvailableHeight + 1
        }}
      >
        landscapeAvailableHeight = {landscapeAvailableHeight}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

What am I missing here? Any suggestion/help is appreciated. Thanks!